# SONY VAIO Laptop black screen/no screen problem after OEM installing ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi

Recently I installed ubuntu18.04 LTS on my Sony Vaio Fit 15E (model no:-SVF15212SNB) laptop using "OEM installation mode" because I wanted to wipe my hard disk and install Ubuntu as the primary OS, earlier lubuntu was installed on my laptop.

After installation I rebooted my laptop as instructed at the end of the installation procedure, the laptop didn't boot there is no screen/black screen and the hard disk indicator led light blinks continuously. I tried booting several times but nothing happened.

I am also unable to enter BIOS by pressing the ASSIST button I am getting the same black screen/no screen. I tried resetting the BIOS by removing and inserting the BIOS battery on Motherboard again getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the hard drive has been damaged after installing ubuntu. Because I had cases where the iso was wrong and I had to reinstall it.

The problem is that I guess you don't have a hard drive reader that connects to another computer via USB. If you have a friend who can lend it would be advisable. Do you have another computer with windows? I recommend it to execute the following command from the cmd to analyze the usb and repair the damaged files with the command:

`chkdsk [DISC LETTER:] /r /f`

If this does not work you could clone the entire system of another ubuntu device to yours with clonezilla or acronis true image (the cloning process is very slow).

After all this process I would clean your device's RAM with a draft because this can also be the cause.
I pass the link on how to do it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7tvfoJYnKE

Comment: Hi Saori, thanks for answering. I already cleaned my laptop's RAM as shown in video you mentioned but the problem still persists. Also i tried to boot into BIOS after removing hardisk and CD Drive but it didn't boot.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can give you is what I previously told you. Remove your hard drive and with a hard drive reader similar to these:

https://www.pccomponentes.com/tooq-hdd-docking-station-usb-30-negra?gclid=CjwKCAjw-vjqBRA6EiwAe8TCk96BiIJY0y93QUhgq-68HYesz5lj-AmVnhMsA_IYcnLhd3vwK8Mw3vwdbwbwbwbw

Connect it to another computer that has windows (you have to insert your disk before turning on the disk reader) and run a cmd, where you will execute the chkdsk command.
When the process is finished, turn off the disk reader and take out your hard drive. Then put it back into your computer and start.

If this does not work, try to recover all the information you can from your hard drive with the reader. This device lets you access all the information on the disk and you can recover several things.

Once you finish copying, reinsert your hard drive and format your device.
If you don't know how to do it, ask me and I will answer you.

Comment: Hi Soari, i will try connecting the laptop hardisk into desktop and perform chkdsk. If problem still persists may be my RAM sticks are dead. My laptop used to boot very late when i installed lubuntu. Thanks for your help. Have a good day.

Comment: Without problems, I will be aware if your problem is solved.